# Resizing Highcharts legend on window resize

Tags: javascript, html, width, highcharts

I want to change the size of Highcharts legend (especially its width). Here is some of the code I tried to use based on research I did:

```
            $(window).resize(changeSummaryLayout);

            function changeSummaryLayout() {
                var w = window.innerWidth;
                if (w < 1370 && w > 992) {
                    for (i = 0; i < charts.length; i++) {
                        charts[i].highcharts().setTitle({ x: -5 });
                        charts[i].highcharts().legend.options.y = 150;
                        charts[i].highcharts().margin[3] = 0;
                        charts[i].highcharts().legend.options.width = 200;
                        charts[i].highcharts().legend.itemStyle.width = 200;
                        for (var index in charts[i].highcharts().series) {
                            charts[i].highcharts().legend.destroyItem(charts[i].highcharts().series[index]);
                        }
                        charts[i].highcharts().legend.render();
                        //charts[i].highcharts().legend.update({ itemStyle150 });
                        //charts[i].highcharts().isDirtyLegend = true;
                        //charts[i].highcharts().redraw();
                        //charts[i].highcharts().isDirtyBox = true;
                    }
                    $('#chartContainer').css('height', '400px');
                    $('.pieChartTotal').css('height', '390px');
                    $('.pieChartCanvasSum').css('height', '330px !important');
                    $('.highcharts-container').children().css('height', '330px');
                    $('.highcharts-background').attr('height', '330px');
                }
```

None of those solutions is worknig to change the width and, what is strange, the width gets updated only after I hover my mouse over legend. Can anyone explain to me why does this happen?

Is there any solution that will work here?

Comment: you need to resize chart legend when chart resize ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try like:

```
 var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
......
}); 


function resizeWindow(){
  chart.legend.options.width = widthyouwanttoadd;
  chart.legend.itemStyle.width = widthyouwanttoadd;
  for(var index in this.chart.series) {
        chart.legend.destroyItem(chart.series[index]);
  }
  chart.legend.render()
}
```